# Фэйлится миграция при изменение поля sqllite & rails

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Все просто: хочу удалить NOT NULL у поля, создаю миграцию, аля

```
class Remove5NullFromUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :users, :email, :string, :null => true, :default => ''
  end
end
```

Это devise'овская табличка, в резульатте, эррор:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:216:in `column'
```

Я уже голову всю сломал, не могу понять, что я делаю не так?
Спасибо

Comment: SQLite не поддерживает изменение столбцов. Сорс ошибки вы можете посмотреть [здесь](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/activerecord/4.1.6/files/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#line=200), подозреваю, что проблема в хитрых типах SQLite, и вместо типа возвращается просто `nil`. Тем не менее, вы не можете сделать `modify column` при работе с SQLite.

Comment: Можно подробнее пожалуйста про modify column? Это делается в миграции?

Comment: Это то, что пытается сделать `change_column`.

Comment: Спасибо! Почитаю. Напишите это как ответ - зачту ;)

Answer (score 1):

Поддерживаю предыдущих. Сам недавно мигрировал с *SQLite* на *Postgres* именно из-за подобных проблем (с миграциями). Лучше переходите на постгрес, и гем есть для переноса базы.

Мануал на хабре: [Перенос данных из одной базы в любую другую](http://habrahabr.ru/post/117797/)